# Find the number of Diagonal Matrices with product of diagonal elements as $27000$

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of $3 \times 3$ Diagonal Matrices with product of diagonal elements as $27000$ with diagonal elements as Natural numbers.

Let $x_1$,$x_2$ and $x_3$ are diagonal elements then we have to find all ordered triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ such that $$x_1 \times x_2 \times x_3=27000=2^3 \times 3^3 \times 5^3$$

Case $1.$ The number of Matrices with two diagonal elements as unity is obviously $3$

Case $2.$ The number of matrices with exactly one diagonal element as unity is given by $$ \binom{3}{1} \times \left((3+1)(3+1)(3+1)-1\right)=189$$

But how can we proceed if None of the Diagonal elements is Unity?

Comment: The matrix setting is a red herring.  You are just asking for ordered factorizations of $27000$ into three factors.

Comment: yes i  just posted directly my book question

Comment: I think it is important to think of things like that because they show other areas of math that may be useful.  In this case, you tagged it as linear algebra but my comment shows that it is not (likely to be) in that area. My parentheses admit that somebody may find a trick to bring it back into linear algebra.  We are asking for the number of ways to find three non-null vectors with non-negative integer components that sum to $(3,3,3)$  I don't think linear algebra can help, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would attack it in a different manner.  If we just think about the factors of $2$ we need to find the number of [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $3$ into $3$ parts.  The stars and bars argument in Wikipedia shows there are ${5 \choose 2}=10$ of them.  We can then multiply the number of choices for each prime, getting $10^3=1000$ ordered factorizations of $27000$

Comment: So weak composition of $3$ means we are actually splitting $3$ either as $3$, $1+2$,$2+1$ and $1+1+1$. so there are four right, can you please clarify on this?

Comment: No, a weak composition allows zero, which is why the number of parts to be  specified.  There are $3+0+0,2+1+0,1+1+1$ and permutations of each.  That gives $10$ total.

Comment: ok i understood so that means if we take factor $2^3$, it can be written in ten possible ways as $2^{3}\times 2^0 \times 2^0$,  $2^{0}\times 2^3 \times 2^0$ and so on. The same thing applies for $3^3$ and $5^3$.  But i have doubt how total number of ordered triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is 1000.

Comment: For each of the $10$ compositions of $2$ you choose one of the $10$ compositions of $3$, giving $10\cdot 10$ choices for $2,3$ together.  Then there are $10$ compositions of $5$.  You have three independent choices to make, so you multiply the number of choices at each step.

Comment: yes that is my doubt, we can choose composition with respect to $2$ in ten ways and similarly for $3$ in ten ways, then obviously third factor will be $\frac{27000}{2^a \times 3^b}$ right? why again we are choosing in ten ways for the last factor

Comment: You are confusing the choices you are making for $2,3$.  You are not choosing the first two factors.  It is like you have three ordered buckets and three identical rocks labeled $2$ to distribute in the three buckets.  There are $10$ ways to do that.  Then you distribute three identical rocks labeled $3$ in the three buckets.  Again $10$ ways.  Finally you distribute three rocks labeled $5$.  You multiply the factors you find in each bucket to get a diagonal entry in the matrix.

Comment: awesome sir now its pretty clear to me. Thanks